# what is the difference between request()->json() and request()->input()

Tags: laravel

What is the difference between request()->json() and request()->input() in laravel:

is there any difference in functionality in laravel.

Answer (score 3):

Both are almost same but having slight difference. Since $request->input() is smart enough to pull userdata from get, post or json. laravel offers $request->json(). there are 2 reasons you might prefer $request->json().

1) You might want to just be more explicit to other programmers on your project about where you're expecting the data to come from.

2) If POST doesn't have the correct application/json headers, $request->input() won't pick it up as JSON, but $request->json() will do.

Answer (score 0):

Basicaly they have a same  funcionalty  the only difference is at naming meaning when you see json you know that you are expecting json data 
while with input you can expecting jason data  but also http request GET OR POST